# Left outer join on Slick/Mysql

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I am having trouble using a left outer join in Slick. I'll start with some code :

```
val articles = (for {
    (article, lecture) <- ArticleDAO leftJoin LectureDAO on (_.id === _.idArticle) if     (article.flux === idFlux)
} yield (article, lecture.isStarred.?)).groupBy(_._1.guid).map {
    case (guid, rows) => rows.first
}
```

PS : The `ArticleDAO` & `LectureDAO` are the objects extending `Table` in opposition to `Article` & `Lecture` which are simple case classes.

This is the error, I am getting when compiling the part above :

```
Don't know how to unpack (models.Article, Option[Boolean]) to T and pack to G
```

I don't really understand this error. I know it has something to do with transformation, composition of queries but I have no idea how to change/fix it. Could some shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is explained here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/bIFH6be99B0 . `.first` is not a query operation at the moment, use `.min` instead.

Comment: Indeed, I also asked the question there ;)